# Current science on increasing running volume while also integrating drills?

Tags: injury-prevention, running-training-plan

*For context: this question is about intermediate runners - i.e., *not* for people starting from zero, nor for sub-3 marathoners, but for runners who have maybe run a year or two and raced some 5Ks, 10Ks or HMs, and have been exposed to drills as mentioned below in their past, and are about to step up to the next race distance, whichever that may be.*

I see two conflicting bits of advice in books and on the 'net:

- You should **either** increase your running volume, running at relatively moderate pace (i.e., easy runs, long runs, maybe careful goal pace runs), **or** you should work on speed via drills (fartleks, intervals, hills etc.). You should not combine the two in a training phase to avoid injury.
- The opposite is true - do your HM or M training while increasing your volume as well as integrating all kinds of different running sessions.

The first seems to be commonplace when listening to / reading advice from running coaches regarding injury prevention.

The latter seems to be especially prevalent in the relatively young app-based adaptive training plans (Garmin, Stryd, Enduco etc.), which usually guard their knowledge pretty well, i.e., they don't often provide much insight in how they came up with their algorithms, and especially not whether their customers had success, or were struck down by injury.

For this question, I am primarily looking for, but have not found (quite possibly due to not using the correct search terms), relatively current studies or meta-studies on this topic.

I am also happy about my two bullet points being corrected. Are they just oversimplified? Have I just misunderstood? I.e., are both true or valid approaches to training, depending on some other factors, and my question is really moot?

Comment: I have not looked into the science, but some of this stems from Training Peaks (A triathlon based training site originally) and their Training Stress Score (TSS). It was an attempt to codify training to the actual stress from a session rather than just raw mileage calculation. That might be an avenue to investigate.

Comment: @johnp, yeah, all these apps/web sites that I mentioned (those are the ones I have personal experience with) have something like the TSS. Interesting point; maybe it was just too hard in the "old days" to manually make the diverse sessions properly comparable and that's where the old rule stems from?

Comment: Possibly just bad correlation - "Well, we increased distance and intensity, and 3 runners got hurt. New rule!" That's how a lot of exercise myths get started and persist. Plus the science behind training volume and injury susceptibility is also somewhat new, there hasn't been a lot of data or studies that I've seen.